# Existing android studio project modules issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, project-structure

I have been trying to open my existing android studio project which was working perfectly fine, but now is giving me issues. I also tried to import it and the issue persisted. The APP folder on ANDROID VIEW is not expandable and when I click on it, it takes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1IHL.png)me to the PROJECT STRUCTURE --> PROJECT SETTINGS --> MODULES.
[This is what appears after I have imported/opened my project[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz3jV.png)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the project is not defined to android studio as a android project .. 
I suggest to remove .idea folder and re-sync gradle

i faced the same issue and after a long search .. I edited /.idea/misc.xml file .. 
the app was read as a java module not android project.

Comment: AndDev thanks for your reply, but I have deleted the .idea folder and synced project with gradle files and still the problem persists.

Comment: AndDev what did you edit on the /.idea/misc.xml file?